# Custom protobuf options of message of type Any in Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, any

I have a GRPC service defined like:

```
message SendEventRequest {
  string producer = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any event = 2;
}

message SendEventResponse {
  string event_name = 1;
  string status = 2;
}

service EventService {
  rpc Send(SendEventRequest) returns (SendEventResponse);
}
```

I also have defined a custom message option:

```
extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
  // event_name is the unique name of the event sent by the clients
  string event_name = 50000;
}
```

What I want to achieve is have clients create custom proto messages that set the `event_name` option to a "constant". For instance:

```
message SomeCustomEvent {
  option (mypackage.event_name) = "some_custom_event";

  string data = 1;
  ...
}
```

That way the service can keep track of what events are being sent. When I do something like this I'm able to get the value of the option from a specific `proto.Message`:

```golang
_, md := descriptor.MessageDescriptorProto(SomeCustomEvent)
mOpts := md.GetOptions()
eventName := proto.GetExtension(mOpts, mypackage.E_EventName)
```

However, when the message is of type `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any.Any` the options are nil. How can I retrieve the `event_name` from the message? I've come across the `protoregistry.MessageTypeResolver`, which looks like it might help, but I would need to figure out a way to dynamically update the proto definitions of the events when clients integrate.

Comment: If you use the ANY type, isn't there functionality added in the Go code to find out which type was sent? Or can't you do a type assertion? This should render the static value unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain the options of an `Any` type, you need its specific `protoreflect.MessageType` so that you can unmarshal it into a specific message. In order to get the message type, you need a `MessageTypeResolver`.

`Any` contains a `type_url` field, which can be used for that purpose. In order to unmarshal the `Any` object into a message of an existing message type:

```golang
// GlobalTypes contains information about the proto message types
var res protoregistry.MessageTypeResolver = protoregistry.GlobalTypes
typeUrl := anyObject.GetTypeUrl()
msgType, _ := res.FindMessageByURL(typeUrl)

msg := msgType.New().Interface()
unmarshalOptions := proto.UnmarshalOptions{Resolver: res}
unmarshalOptions.Unmarshal(anyObject.GetValue(), msg)
```

After having the specific message, you can simply get the option you need:

```golang
msgOpts := msg.ProtoReflect().Descriptor().Options()
eventName := proto.GetExtension(msgOpts, mypackage.E_EventName)
```

Note that `proto.GetExtension` will panic if the message doesn't extend the `event_name` option, and it needs to be recovered. This block can be added at the beginning of the function:

```golang
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        // err is a named return parameter of the outer function
        err = fmt.Errorf("recovering from panic while extracting event_name from proto message: %s", r)
    }
}()
```

EDIT: Note that the application has to import the package containing the proto definitions in order for `protoregistry.GlobalTypes` to recognize the type. You could do something like this in your code:

`var _ mypackage.SomeEvent`

Answer (score 0):

The [any.ANY](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/master/types/known/anypb/any.pb.go#L211) type in Go contains the `TypeUrl` field which contains the type of the message that was sent. You can then use that to [UnmarshalAny](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#UnmarshalAny) to the correct, generated Go type.

Link to a [complete guide](https://medium.com/@pokstad/sending-any-any-thing-in-golang-with-protobuf-3-95f84838028d) on how to work with `any.ANI`.

Comment: This only half-helped me. But I found a solution, which I'll post as a solution later today.

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to Boyan's answer, I found it needs to pass `protoregistry.ExtensionTypeResolver` variable to assign `proto.UnmarshalOptions.Resolver`, which looks like:

```golang
var extRes protoregistry.ExtensionTypeResolver = protoregistry.GlobalTypes
unmarshalOptions := proto.UnmarshalOptions{Resolver: extRes}
```