# How to extract field from protobuf message without schema

Tags: go, reflection, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling, proto

According to [this issue](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/927), the [protoreflect](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect) package provides APIs for accessing the "unknown fields" of protobuf messages, but I don't see any way to use it if there isn't any existing schema. Basically, I want to perform a "weak decode", similar to what the JSON unmarshaller does if the output is of type `map[string]interface{}`.

The example from [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.26.0/proto#UnmarshalOptions) looks like this:

```golang
err := UnmarshalOptions{DiscardUnknown: true}.Unmarshal(b, m)
```

where `b` is the input byte slice and `m` is the output message, which needs to be initialised somehow, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845135/1174378). I was thinking that [dynamicpb](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/dynamicpb) can be used for this purpose, but it doesn't look possible without having an existing [MessageDescriptor](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.26.0/reflect/protoreflect#MessageDescriptor) and that's where I got stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the low level [protowire](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.26.0/encoding/protowire) package. Here is a full example, where I extract two fields of type `uint64` (which happen to be assigned [field numbers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#assigning_field_numbers) 4 and 5 in the original schema):

```golang
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protowire"

func getData(src []byte) (creationTime, expiryTime uint64, err error) {
    remaining := src
    for len(remaining) > 0 {
        fieldNum, wireType, n := protowire.ConsumeTag(remaining)
        if n < 0 {
            return 0, 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to consume tag: %w", protowire.ParseError(n))
        }
        remaining = remaining[n:]

        switch fieldNum {
        case 4: // Expiry time
            if wireType != protowire.VarintType {
                return 0, 0, fmt.Errorf("unexpected type for expiry time field: %d", wireType)
            }
            expiryTime, n = protowire.ConsumeVarint(remaining)
        case 5: // Creation time
            if wireType != protowire.VarintType {
                return 0, 0, fmt.Errorf("unexpected type for creation time field: %d", wireType)
            }
            creationTime, n = protowire.ConsumeVarint(remaining)
        default:
            n = protowire.ConsumeFieldValue(fieldNum, wireType, remaining)
        }
        if n < 0 {
            return 0, 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to consume value for field %d: %w", fieldNum, protowire.ParseError(n))
        }
        remaining = remaining[n:]
    }

    return
}
```